# get list of entries from a csv files that are not older than a given time in powershell

Tags: date, powershell, datetime

I have a csv file named events.csv that contains list of events like below

```
"Severity","EventId","Event","Trigger (MM/DD/YYYY 24H)","SourceID","Source"
Information,1866,vol.resize.fail:VolumeResizeFailed,05/28/2015 12:25:42,286,controller1:/volA
Information,1865,vol.resize.success:VolumeResizeSuccess,05/28/2015 12:24:19,286,controller1:/volA
```

Now I want to get the list of entries from the file where the TriggerColumn(time) is less than 24 hours from the current time.

So my current code looks like this

```
$dateToCompare = (Get-date).AddDays(-1)

$eventsList = Import-Csv $eventsReportFileName  | where-object {$_."Trigger (MM/DD/YYYY 24H)" -gt $dateToCompare}
```

The date comparison inst working because it says they are of different type

```
PS H:\> $a."Trigger (MM/DD/YYYY 24H)"

05/28/2015 12:25:42

05/28/2015 12:24:19

PS H:\> $dateToCompare = (Get-date).AddDays(-1)

PS H:\> $dateToCompare

Thursday, May 28, 2015 7:24:30 PM
```

But if i typecast I am not able to format the date. The output of the CSV file is fixed and cant change it. All I can do is change the format of Get-date and
play.

Any ideas to solve is appreciated

Answer (score 2):

If the date is coming in from a csv, it is a string and not a datetime object. Instead of turning your (Get-Date).AddDays(-1) into a string, turn your MM/DD/YYYY 24H into a DateTime object.

Like this.

```
$eventsList = Import-Csv $eventsReportFileName | Where-Object -FilterScript {[DateTime]::Parse($_."Trigger (MM/DD/YYYY 24H)") -gt $dateToCompare}
```

Comment: I thought about doing it the other way around by converting `$dateToCompare` to string `$dateToCompare = [string](get-date -Format "...")` - but this would cause issue with doing the -gt comparison, your script answer is much better!
upboated

Comment: Firstly, thanks Chris Martin. But when I tried running the code snippet, I still get the following error. String was not recognized as a valid DateTime $dateToCompare = (Get-date).AddDays(-1)
$eventsList = Import-Csv $eventsReportFileName | Where-Object -FilterScript {[DateTime]::Parse($_."Trigger (MM/DD/YYYY 24H)") -gt $dateToCompare}
Exception calling "Parse" with "1" argument(s): "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."At line:5 char:78
+ $eventsList = Import-Csv $eventsReportFileName | Where-Object -FilterScript {[Da

Comment: Are all of your strings in the "Trigger (MM/DD/YYYY 24H)" column in exactly the format you listed? (like 05/28/2015 12:25:42)? If not, can I have an example of some that are different? That error shows that the String input is not being read correctly by [DateTime]::Parse(). We can use [DateTime]::ParseExact("<your format>") if they are different.

Comment: Hi Chris,  Thanks for your response. Yes they are all in the same format. As far as I understood, $_."Trigger (MM/DD/YYYY 24H)" is an array and in my case it returned the entire column. Where as DateTime]::Parse() is expecting a string. So I did a foreach and used DateTime]::Parse() and it worked.